# An application of Borel-Caratheodory theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f(z)$ is analytic function in the disk $|z|\le R$ and $A(r)=\max_{|z|=r}Re(z)$ then prove that $r<R$

$$\max_{|z|=r}\left|\frac{f^n(z)}{n!}\right|\le \frac{2^{n+2}R}{(R-r)^{n+1}}\{A(r)+|f(0)|\}$$

MY attempt

Using Cauchy generalized integral formula

$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int _c\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}$

then $\max_{|z|=r}\left|\frac{f^n(z)}{n!}\right|=\left|\max_{|z|=r} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _c\frac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\right|$

and i think we can solve by using Borel caratheodory theorem

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic function on $|z|\le R$ and let $M(r)=\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$ and $A(r)=\max_{|z|=r}Re f(z)$ then  for $0<r<R$

$$ M(r)\le \frac{2r}{R-r}A(R)+\frac{R+r}{R-r}|f(0)|$$

from here how to processed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Barista Thank you for pointing the flaw in my answer. So here is an error proof "Proof" of the above problem.

**Borel-Caratheodory Theorem:** Let $f(z)$ be analytic for $|z|\le R$ and let $M(r)=max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$ and $A(r)=max_{|z|=r}Re(f(z))$ then for $0<r<R$ we have $$M(r)\le \frac{2r}{R-r}A(R)+\frac{R+r}{R-r}|f(0)|<\frac{R+r}{R-r}\{A(R)+|f(0)|\}.$$

Now we start with $$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(\omega)-f(0)}{(\omega - z)^{n+1}}d\omega...(1)$$ where $C$ is the circle $|\omega - z|=\delta = \frac{1}{2}(R-r)$ and which also ensures that $C$ lies totally in $|z|=R$. Now apply Borel-Caratheodory theorem on $f(z)-f(0)$ we get, $$\operatorname{max}_{|z|=r}|f(z)-f(0)|\le \frac{4R}{R-r}\left\{A(R)+|f(0)|\right\}$$ and now by equation (1) we get, $$max_{|z|=r}|f^{(n)}(z)|\le \frac{4Rn!}{(R-r)\delta ^n}\{A(R)+|f(0)|\}$$ So, $$max_{|z|=r}|\frac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!}|\le \frac{2^{n+2}R}{(R-r){n+1}}\{A(R)+|f(0)|\}.$$

**For more details please read *Introduction to theory of entire functions-A. S. B. Holland*

===============================OLD ANSWER=======================
First, observe that, $r<R$ and so for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have,
$$\left(\frac{2r}{R-r}\right)^n>0\text{ and }\left(1+\frac{r}{R}\right)<2$$
$$\implies \left(1+\frac{r}{R}\right)<2<2\left(\frac{2r}{R-r}\right)^n \text{[There is a flaw in this line so I've edited my answer]}$$
$$\implies \left(1+\frac{r}{R}\right)<2\left(\frac{2r}{R-r}\right)^n.....(1)$$

Now by Cauchy Inequality, $$|a_n|\le \frac{M(r)}{r^n}.....(2)$$ where $\displaystyle M(r)=\max_{|z|=r}\{|f(z)|\}$ and $a_n=\frac{f^n(z)}{n!}$ is the coefficient of power series of $f$ in the given domain.

Now finally using Borel-Caratheodory theorem we have,
$$M(r)\le \frac{2r}{R-r}A(R)+\frac{R+r}{R-r}|f(0)|$$
$$\implies |a_n|=|\frac{f^n(z)}{n!}|\le \frac{1}{r^n}\frac{R+r}{R-r}\{A(R)+|f(0)|\}$$
$$\implies |\frac{f^n(z)}{n!}|\le \frac{2^{n+1}R}{(R-r)^{n+1}}\{A(R)+|f(0)|\}$$
This inequality follows directly from (1) by some simple algebraic manipulation. Now since the RHS is independent of $z$ so taking maximum on the boundary $|z|=r$ we obtain, $$\max_{|z|=r}|\frac{f^n(z)}{n!}|\le \frac{2^{n+1}R}{(R-r)^{n+1}}\{A(R)+|f(0)|\}$$

Hope this works.

Comment: ...very nice way of thinking and answer ..thankyou...

Comment: welcome! basically its just an application of Borel-Caratheodory theorem

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya How do you know the second inequality? We don't know if $\frac{2r}{R-r}> 1$ or not.

Comment: @barista Thanks for finding my error. I've also corrected that proof on my notes too.